# Lenovo e420s overheating

Tags: lenovo, overheating

I recently bought a Lenovo e420s and decided to install Ubuntu (first time). The interface is great, but the computer overheats horribly (the fan is on full all the time and the cpu temperature is much higher than in Windows). In other words, it's not a fan problem, but an OS problem. Does anybody have a fix that is implementable by a luddite? I'd like to use linux, but it's not possible if it turns my computer into a radiator.

Thanks.